# How to extract unique column values in data frame in R and count together the amount of appearances

Tags: r, dataframe, unique, multiple-columns

I am trying to extract only unique values of a certain column in a data frame. Here is an example:

```
df <- data.frame(word1=c("not","but","not","not","never","nor","never","not"),
      word2=c("beautiful","nice","strong","awesome","beautiful","beautiful","strong","nice"),
      n=c(400,378,29,10,222,43,620,90))

df
```

I would like to filter the second column "word2" to only contain unique words, so only that "beautiful" appears one time and that the column "n" adds together all the counts for all "beautiful", "strong" etc.

So it should like this:

```
df.unique <- data.frame(word2=c("beautiful","nice","strong","awesome"),
             n=c(665,468,649,10))
df.unique
```

In this example the column "word2" only contains 4 words but my real data frame contains thousands of words so i cannot use operators like "==beautiful,strong..."

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please check your 'df'.  It is giving errors

Comment: yes I noticed it too I changed it now

Comment: Isn't this just `df %>% group_by(word2) %>% summarise(n = sum(n))` or `aggregate(n ~ word2, df, sum)`

Comment: @ akrun amazing, thank you sooo much both approaches work fantastically! I am very new to coding and you helped me a lot thank you!